# Remove node from a linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list

I have been stuck on this function to remove node from a list, if there are two names in the list they are both gone.  If Anne and John are in the list and I want to delete Anne, then my list is empty, John is gone.

What am I missing to keep the connection in the list if I delete a node init?

```
bool ContactList::remove(string key)
{
      NodePtr prev = NULL;

       for(NodePtr temp = head; temp != NULL; temp = temp->link)
       {
            if(temp->data.key == key)
            {
                if(prev == NULL)
                {
                    head = temp->link;
                    delete temp;
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    prev = temp->link;
                    delete temp;
                    return true;
                 }

             }

         }
     return false;
}
```

Comment: Because your logic is wrong.. the else part in the loop will never be executed. Recheck your logic. May be, in the for loop you have forgot to set 'prev'  variable.

Comment: You also need to set `prev`'s link, not `prev`.

Comment: @dornhege prev->link is need to be set in else part, and prev is needed to be updated at the end of the loop.

Comment: You also don't *need* to special case the head-case if you use the pointers *in the list* (not just their values; the actual pointers) for enumeration. [See how here](http://pastebin.com/xQgDYAsj).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't keeping `prev` up to date in every iteration of your loop.  You want something like:

```
prev = temp;
```

at the bottom of your `for` loop.

Comment: Thank you so much, that is what was missing.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this function

```
bool ContactList::remove(string key)
{
  NodePtr prev = NULL;

   for(NodePtr temp = head; temp != NULL; temp = temp->link)
   {
        if(temp->data.key == key)
        {
            if(prev == NULL)
            {
                head = temp->link;
                delete temp;
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                prev->link = temp->link;   // change.
                delete temp;
                return true;
             }

         }
         prev = temp;      // change.
     }
 return false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that is what was missing.